# How to Delete from array powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How can i delete row from array which is `pscustomobject` in a loop?

Getting errors if i use this in the loop:

```
$a = $a | where {condition to remove lines}
```

Getting the below error

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
```

any suggetion to remove row from array.

Comment: Custom object is not an array.

Comment: Please show the actual condition you use inside the `where` scriptblock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me make some general points, given the generic title of the question:

- **Arrays** (in .NET, which underlies PowerShell) are ***fixed-size* data structures**. As such, **you cannot delete elements from them *directly***.
- However, you **can create a *new* array that is a *copy*** of the original one with the **unwanted elements *omitted***, and that is what the pipeline approach facilitates:

```sh
# Sample array.
$a = 1, 2, 3

# "Delete" element 2 from the array, which yields @(1, 3).
# @(...) ensures that the result is treated as an array even if only 1 element is returned.
$a = @($a | Where-Object { $_ -ne 2 })
```

PowerShell automatically captures the output from a pipeline in an *array* (of type `[System.Object[]]`) when you assign it to a variable.

However, since PowerShell automatically *unwraps* a *single-element* result, you need `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to ensure that `$a` remains an *array* even if only a single element was returned - the alternative would be to *type-constrain* the variable as an array:

```sh
[array] $a = $a | Where-Object { $_ -ne 2 }
```

Note that even though the result is assigned back to input variable `$a`, `$a` now technically contains a *new* array (and the old one, if it is not being referenced elsewhere, will eventually be garbage-collected).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> How can i delete row from array which is pscustomobject

As [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) points out, `[pscustomobject]` are not arrays, but perhaps you meant to say that you have an array whose *elements* are custom objects, in which case the above approach applies.
Alternatively, if the array to delete elements from is stored in a *property* of a custom object, send that property's value through the pipeline instead, and assign the results back to that property.

The error message occurs when you try to use the `+` operator with a `[pscustomobject]` instance as the LHS, which is not supported; e.g.:

```sh
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar' }) + 1
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
...
```

PowerShell doesn't know how to "add" something to a custom object, so it complains.